# How do I configure additional MessageListener to the RedisMessageListenerContainer provided by Spring Session?

Tags: spring-boot, redis, publish-subscribe, spring-session

I had a working Redis pub sub configuration as explained on the spring boot redis pub sub guide.

Here is the bean configuration for the RedisMessageListenerContainer

```
@Bean
RedisMessageListenerContainer container(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {

    RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.addMessageListener(listenerAdapter, new ChannelTopic("broadcast"));
    return container;
}
```

Now I wanted to utilize spring session backed by redis.
So, I added a configuration class as this.

```
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class HttpSessionConfig {

}
```

Now, because RedisHttpSessionConfig already defines a RedisMessageListenerContainer , I am getting this exception on start.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: container,redisMessageListenerContainer

To get around that, I comment out the RedisMessageListenerContainer defined in my ApplicationConfig so that there is only one container bean but the problem then is

How do I configure my listener to add to the existing container provided by 
redisMessageListenerContainer?

Ok I was able to get around the problem by removing the RedisMessageListenerContainer  bean, and injecting it as a method parameter in my MessageListenerAdaper bean configuration like so.

```
@Bean
MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(RedisMessageListenerContainer container, PushNotificationsService receiver) {

    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter = new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
    listenerAdapter.setSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<NotificationMessage>(NotificationMessage.class));
    container.addMessageListener(listenerAdapter, new ChannelTopic("broadcast"));
    return listenerAdapter;
}
```

But this does not seem a clean solution, as I am decorating the RedisMessageListenerContainer bean from inside the MessageListenerAdaper bean.
Any better ideas?

Answer (score -2):

You can override the `RedisMessageListenerContainer` bean provided by Spring Session's `RedisHttpSessionConfiguration` by naming your `RedisMessageListenerContainer` bean `redisMessageListenerContainer`.

Of course, in this case you also need to manually configure the required [message listeners](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java#L92-L96) with your bean and, if necessary, also apply other parts of `RedisHttpSessionConfiguration#redisMessageListenerContainer`.

Comment: Please provide snippets or links. Doesn't make any sense without that